# Content of canvas flashes, some kind of loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, animate-cc

I don't know much of javascript and HTML5 Canvas, I have been creating simple games with Animate CC.

I tried load a image on canvas, and works. But the image just flashes and disapear. (when I refresh the page for example)

Code:

```
self = this;
self.stop();

loadingImage();
function loadingImage() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var myImage = new Image(1024, 768);

    myImage.onload = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
        console.log(myCanvas);
        console.log(myImage);
    }
    myImage.src = 'images/Koala.jpg';
}
```

The same thing occurs when I try make a input text field, it flashes as if the timeline is looping, but is not. (you can see flash when click)

Code:

```
self=this;
self.stop();

var input = new CanvasInput({
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
    x:100,
    y:100,
    width: 500,
    fontWeight:'bold',
});
```

I think Animate CC generate a loop automatic, but in my project is disabled. You can check the .js.

Image:
http://www.dfrikki.com.br/test/

Text Field:
http://www.dfrikki.com.br/test2/

Someone can help me to solve this?

Comment: The frame rate is defined as 30 fps, but timeline is stopped.

Comment: It looks like loadingImage() is being called multiple times are you sure this code is not being called by some loop?

Comment: The timeline is stopped, but I think the animate CC make a loop automatic, with tween.js. I don't know for sure.
In textbox.js there this, but some reason loop goes on.

(lib.textbox = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
if (loop == null) { loop = false; } this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

Comment: I think I get it, in .html, Animate CC automatic makes a Listener 'tick' for the stage. I just exclude this line so loop stop.
I will make some test now. but seems to work. Guys, sorry for my bad english.